# Grammaticality of sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is this cleft construction grammatical?

> It is from the metastasis of malignant tumours to form secondary tumours that ultimately causes cancers.

I feel that the 'from' here is superfluous, but I am unsure whether its redundancy affects the sentence's grammaticality. Thoughts?

Comment: The sentence looks completely wrong to me.  The subordinate clause here appears to be "ultimately causes cancers", but that's not right, because it doesn't have a subject.  The sentence would only be correct if you took out the *from*.  It's possible that I'm misinterpreting the sentence, but it looks to me like the author was trying to write in a more high-flown way than they were really able to.

Answer (score 2):

"From" in this case makes the sentence not only ungrammatical, but confusing, as it changes the structure. Without it, the sentence flows fine:

> It is [the metastasis of malignant tumors to form secondary tumors] that ultimately causes cancers.

Here, the bracketed phrase is the subject phrase.

Using "from" in this sentence would require you to restructure the second half, for example:

> It is [from the metastasis of malignant tumors to form secondary tumors] that cancer originates.

Here, the bracketed phrase, including "from," is a prepositional phrase modifying "originates."

Comment: +1 and to add that in general, to test whether a cleft sentence is grammatical, remove the "It is" and "that", and see if the remaining phrases make a sensible sentence. "*The metastasis... ultimately causes cancers*" is a good sentence. "***From** the metastasis... ultimately causes cancers*" isn't a good sentence.